# Kubernetes Load Balancer Terminating SSL to Reverse Proxy Ingress DigitalOcean

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, load-balancing, digital-ocean, nginx-ingress

*I had my original infrastructure built around this tutorial. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes.*

Now I am trying to migrate to managing my own cert and terminating SSL at the load balancer.

With my YAML updates, the load balancer in DigitalOcean shows that all nodes are unhealthy and I the URL response with "503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request." However, the endpoint shows a secure HTTPS connection.  What am I doing wrong?

**My new non-functional YAML definitions below.**

**LoadBalancer**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-redirect-http-to-https: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-certificate-id: "**************"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: http
```

**Ingress**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "50m"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - ******.com
        - api.*******.com
  rules:
    - host: **********.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: frontend-angular
              servicePort: 80
    - host: api.********.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: backend-server
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Hi! How did you generate the certificate in DigitalOcean? All the examples I found are having a droplet, but none simple for K8S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached out to DigitalOcean support (which is incredible). My issue was I didn't create the ingress-nginx pod. These are the two steps, as listed in the tutorial, that I missed.

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.26.1/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml`

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.26.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml`.

My actual YAML definitions were correct.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is just using Digital Ocean Marketplace (https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/nginx-ingress-controller).

Installing it manually will cause a lot of issues due do outdated yml files.